# how to include computed data in the solr query response

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to sort my solr queries using a rather complex formula. I think I can get it to work by setting the right function in the sort parameter of the query, but I would like to check my work by seeing the explicit value of the function for each document.

I would like to do this by including the computed value as a field in the result, and then just sorting on that field. Is this the right approach, and if so how can I do this, or is there another approach? I have tried enabling debugquery, but I think it only explains the relevancy score, not the value that was used to sort the results.

In the admin dashboard, my solr-spec and lucene-spec are both 4.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [function query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery).

You can use the LocalParams syntax i.e. `{!func}` or set `defType=func`. (You may not want to use `_val_` hook, since your function value then becomes a component in the score.) The score is the value of the function, so your results are automatically sorted by the function value. Fetch the score with `fl=*,score`.